# not able to locate all forms on page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using asp.net and have placed two bootstrap modals on the page, both of which contain a form element in them.  asp.net brings in a form also, which wraps everything, so in total i should have 3 forms on the page.  whenever i try to locate the 2nd form (DevGroupFormEdit) jquery is not able to locate it, returns undefined.  If i try `$("form").length` i get 2, it shows one is the asp.net form (id=aspnetForm) other is the 3rd one (id=newDevGroupForm).  below are the two modals, they are contained in the same parent div:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="editDevGroupModal" tabindex="-3" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-bind="with: selectedTag">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <form id="DevGroupFormEdit">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Dev Group</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 paddingTop3">
                                Group Name:
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="text" id="txtEditName" name="txtEditName" class="form-control" data-bind="value: copyname" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="btnCancelEdit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm buttonsize" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm buttonsize">Save</button>
                    <div class="marginTop10">
                        <span class="label-danger" id="lblErrorEdit" style="display: none;">An error occurred while saving this record.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

and the one which jquery is able to find is:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="newDevGroupModal" tabindex="-2" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <form id="newDevGroupForm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Create New Dev Group</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 paddingTop3">
                                Group Name:
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="text" id="txtNewDevGroupName" name="txtNewDevGroupName" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm buttonsize" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSaveNew" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm buttonsize">Save</button>
                    <div class="marginTop10">
                        <span class="label-danger" id="lblNewError" style="display: none;">An error occurred while creating this record.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

they are very similar, just not sure why the 2nd one (id=DevGroupFormEdit) keeps returning undefined, or why $('form') is also not able to locate it.

Comment: Provide your javascript code

Comment: Not sure why you're getting undefined. I tried `$("#DevGroupFormEdit")` and it worked as expected

Comment: @Pavlo my js code to get to the element is var form = $("#DevGroupFormEdit");  when i check form is shows undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "asp.net brings in a form also, which wraps everything"

This is your problem. You can't nest forms. If you inspect element, you'll note that your `<form>` tag is getting stripped out by the DOM.

The only way to fix is to not nest forms.

Side note: In testing, Firefox and Chrome stripped out one form tag and left the other nested. IE stripped out one form tag and moved the 2nd form outside of the "asp.net" form that is wrapping everything.

Comment: I just tried something to confirm, I set a breakpoint on the btnSave click event I had, when that trigger I ran the following: $("#btnSave").parent().parent() --> <div class=​"modal-content">​…​</div>​

$("#btnSave").parent().parent().parent() --> <div class=​"modal-dialog">​…​</div>​  it seems like what you said the form tag was stripped out.  as the parent().parent().parent() should have brought me to the form tag.

Comment: i was using Chrome's Dev tools when I was debugging and saw what you had mentioned.